# Gulp use changed-in-place with multiple tasks that depend on each other

Tags: gulp

I'm using the `gulp-changed-in-place` package to only run certain Gulp tasks with the files that have changed (https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/gulp-changed-in-place). I'm having an issue where I only want to run my linting and code style tasks on changed files to speed up development time.

My current setup is as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var changedInPlace = require('gulp-changed-in-place');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var jscs = require('gulp-jscs');

var config = {
    paths: {
        js: './app/**/*.js'
    }
}

gulp.task('jscs', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
        .pipe(changedInPlace())
        .pipe(jscs())
        .pipe(jscs.reporter())
        .pipe(jscs.reporter('fail'));
});

gulp.task('lint', ['jscs'], function() {
    return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
        .pipe(changedInPlace())
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});

gulp.task('js', ['lint'], function() {
    // do some stuff
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js']);
});
```

The issue is probably pretty obvious. The `js` task has a dependency on the `lint` task which itself has a dependency on the `jscs` task - so the `jscs` task runs first. It accesses `changedInPlace()` which causes the cache to get updated and therefore the `changedInPlace()` call from the `lint` task doesn't think anything has changed and doesn't check the files I expect.

Has anyone used this package with this issue and do you have any suggestions on what to do? Also open to other ways of accomplishing the task - only running the `js` task on changed files.